# Get specific time threshold in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a console app that will choose records based on if the user has chosen to be notified daily at a specific hour of the day as well as all records where the user has chosen hourly.
The job will run every 15 minutes. 
How do I find a threshold of time  between 5 minutes before and 5 minutes after the top of the hour?

This is my code

```
Declare @Now datetime
Declare @NowHour int
Declare @NowMinute int
Declare @NewNow nvarchar(50)

Set @Now = {fn Now()}
Set @NowHour = (SELECT DATENAME(hh, @Now))
Set @NowMinute = (SELECT DATENAME(mi, @Now))
Set @NewNow = Cast(Cast(@NowHour As nvarchar(2)) + ':' + Cast(@NowMinute As nvarchar(2)) as Time)
Select @Now, @NowHour, @NowMinute, @NewNow

Select *  From vw_consumerAlerts 
Where  casexid not in
(Select casexid from alerthistory)  
And Name = 'Always' 
Or ([Hour] Between DateAdd(minute, -5, @NewNow) And DateAdd(minute, -5, @NewNow))
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.
```

I got it, I had [Hour] and @NewNow swapped, now I get the correct results with:

```
    (@NewNow Between DateAdd(minute, -5, [Hour]) And DateAdd(minute, 5, [Hour]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have defined @TheHour as being the hour in question with 00 minutes/seconds:

```
WHERE mydatecol BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -5, @TheHour) AND DATEADD(minute, 5, @TheHour)
```

UPDATE

See this:

```
select 1
where cast('1/1/2010 1:04pm' as time) 
    between cast('1/1/2010 12:55pm' AS time) 
    and cast ('1/1/2010 1:05pm' as time)
```

time and datetime are different, so you need to cast your datetime to time as I've done in the crude example here.

So in your case:

```
Select *  From vw_consumerAlerts 
Where  casexid not in
    (Select casexid from alerthistory)  
And Name = 'Always' 
Or ([Hour] Between cast(DateAdd(minute, -5, @NewNow) as time)
    And cast(DateAdd(minute, -5, @NewNow) as time))
```

Comment: I assume you didnt test this first, dateadd(minute, -5, @theHour)

Comment: GAH I'm always getting those two parameters reversed.  Sorry, fixing.

Comment: I put my sql code above, The between doesn't seem to work. I'm missing something little and dumb I know... just cant think anymore

Comment: the [Hour] column is defined as Time(0) with values of 06:00:00  and 15:00:00, etc